# Call the update method from index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

my question sounds a little bit stupid but i doesn't found an answer alone, that's why i ask.

How can i call my controller update method (or another custom one) from the index-Page of my view?

I have something like:

```
<% @user = User.find_by_id(1) %>
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

but i doesn't want the first line. I want just call the controller and a custom (or the update)-method. Not with a special object.

In this method i take an array from form-entries and update my database.
That works but how can i connect the form with the controller custom method?

Thanks

Comment: I would be useful to see the full controller method, and the full index page (or the relevant form code).

Comment: Already solved with the first answer. I didn't know that i could use `:url` for a path from my `routes.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link any button to any controller action:

- 1)Create a new route to the controller method.

Then link the button:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: new_route_path() do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks. That first part solved my problem. I created a route to the users#update and call the method now with: `<%= form_for :user, url: usersupdate_path() do |f| %>`. Thats all what i wanted.